# How can i filter data by checkbox check or uncheck

Tags: php

I have a few checkbox like below. and when one checkbox checked it must load result from mysql and when unchecked again it must load result without page refresh.

Almost it is same with http://www.facebook.com/find-friends/browser/

How can i do?

```
 <div class="tags">  <label><input type="checkbox" class="arts" /> Arts </label> <label><input type="checkbox" class="computers" /> Computers </label> <label><input type="checkbox" class="health" /> Health </label> <label><input type="checkbox" class="video-games" /> Video Games </label> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with JavaScript, and with jQuery look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: how can do with a few checkbox , i need append criterias

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily accomplished using jQuery (as stated above).  In general, you'll go through a series of 'find something' then 'do something' tasks. I'm no javascript expert, but my feeble attempt at the logic should get you started on the right path.

The jQuery logic will look something like this:

- "listen" for a change in the status of the checkbox see http://api.jquery.com/change/
- set a var = the result that you get from an ajax call which pulls the information you want see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- append (or remove) that var depending on the state of the checkbox see http://api.jquery.com/append/ and http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax.

As people suggested, jQuery allows you to do this easily.

**Example:**

In a JavaScript file:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/get-data',
  type: 'GET',
  data: { tags: anArrayOfCheckedCheckboxes }, // get the checked checkboxes the way you want
  complete: function(response) {
    // do what do you need with the response (display results for example)
  }
});
```

On PHP's side (*/get-data* URL):

```
$tags = $_GET['tags'];
// get the results from the database
return json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of checked checkbox  $(‘[name=”hobbies”:checked]’).val() and for unchecked box you can use $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")